# Where to config the Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler on Google Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

I create cluster on `Google Kubernetes Engine` with `Cluster Autoscaler` option  enabled.
I want to config the scaling behavior such as `--scale-down-delay-after-delete` according to https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md .

But I found no Pod or Deployment on kube-system which is cluster autoscaler.

Anyone has ideas?

---

Edit: 
I am **not** saying `Horizontal Pod Autoscaler`.

And I hope I can configure it as like this :

```
$ gcloud container clusters update cluster-1 --enable-autoscaling --scan-interval=5 --scale-down-unneeded-time=3m
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.update) unrecognized arguments:
  --scan-interval=5
  --scale-down-unneeded-time=3m
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, but for my understand I guess you are looking for https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Comment: cluster autoscaler (GCE layer... scales up and down the running GCE VM instances)
vs.
horizontal pod autoscaler (GKE layer... scales up and down the replicas in pod deployments)

Comment: I mean Cluster Autoscaler, it's an option on GKE. and its more about cluster than horizontal pod autoscaler.

Comment: Did you manage to find  a solution to this by any chance @WeiChingLin?

Comment: I've asked this question here as well: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/966

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible according to https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/966

Probably because there is no way to access the executable (which it seems to be) on GKE.

You can't even view the logs of the autoscaler on GKE: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues/972

Answer (score 0):

One way is to not enable the GKE autoscaler, and then manually install it on a worker node - per the project's docs:

> Users can put it into kube-system namespace (Cluster Autoscaler doesn't scale down node with non-mirrored kube-system pods running on them) and set a priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical property on your pod spec (to prevent your pod from being evicted).

https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler#deployment

I would also think you could annotate the autoscaler pod(s) with the following:

`"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"`

Answer (score -1):

If i correclty understand you need this:

Check your deployments name by:

```
kubectl get deployments
```

And autoscale  it by:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment your_deployment_name --cpu-percent=100 --min=1 --max=10
```

Comment: to see it, type `kubectl get hpa`

Comment: The cluster-autoscaler will add nodes / remove nodes based on if for example pods are pending, or if a node is empty for 10 minutes. The question is: how to configure the 10 minute interval.